# Error running docker and nodemcu-build in linux (debian)

Tags: linux, docker, nodemcu

I am trying to get Docker NodeMCU build running in a linux (debian) environment.

When I run:

> docker run --rm -it -v /root/jsrc/pjsg/nodemcu-firmware
> marcelstoer/nodemcu-build

I get the following error:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>
> cp: cannot stat 'tools/esp-open-sdk.tar.gz': No such file or directory

I have found solutions to this problem for windows environments, but not for linux.  I think the problem lies in my not understanding the instruction:

> "Start Docker and change to the NodeMCU firmware directory (in the
> Docker console)"

The docker service is running, and i can run docker to create a container.

Comment: The exact command is documented at https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build#run-this-image-with-docker and that would have worked in your case as well. I'm always interested in improvements if I see that it seems not clear enough. Just let me know.

Comment: I am a linux user and new to docker.  I didn't understand what was meant by the instruction "Start Docker and change to the NodeMCU firmware directory (in the Docker console)".  This doesn't apply to the linux environment. A linux example, just below your windows example, may be helpful.

Comment: I only use Linux occasionally (I'm on Mac) but I don't see why this doesn't apply. Can you explain please? The add-on "(in the Docker console)" may sound superfluous though for Linux users.

Comment: I have to break this into 2 parts due to character length restrictions. Part 1:   As a brand new user of docker and nodemcu-build there was a couple of confusing (for me) instructions: (i) the displayed command "docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build" doesn't work in linux (even if you replace 'pwd' with a user or root password), you need to replace 'pwd' with the full path to the nodemcu-firmware directory;

Comment: Part 2:  (ii) the instruction "change to the NodeMCU firmware directory (in the Docker console)" sent me looking for an interactive shell (for example, in linux if you enter "python" you are placed into an interactive shell aka console) - i looked for a linux/docker equivalent that would allow me to change to the target directory .  There is sufficient information in the instructions for a linux user to figure it out, but a quick description of the steps for linux users (like the windows example that is there) would eliminate some confusion.

Comment: Here is an example of a quick Linux instruction:
1- start docker:  service docker start
2- build firmware: docker run --rm -it -v /full/path/to/nodemcu-firmware:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
3- note: if you are not running as root you may need to run docker using sudo

Comment: Great tool btw!  Is it possible to specify which modules are included in the build, and is it possible to include a "description" which appears when the firmware is run? (like the description that is shown when firmware from the cloud build service is run).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll think about it. [`pwd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwd) has nothing to do with "password", it's the standard Unix command to **p**rint the **w**orking **d**irectory. Note it's not `pwd` but  ` `pwd` `  with back ticks. Therefore, my instructions work generically across platforms just as-is. I'd like to discuss the other questions in separate "issues" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  example of the correct command in linux is:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /root/jsrc/pjsg/nodemcu-firmware:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

Notes:

- in the above example replace /root/jsrc/pjsg/ with the full path to the nodemcu-firmware in your filesystem
- the docker build requires that the nodemcu-firmware be downloaded from github.com using git clone (git must be installed in your linux environment)
- make sure docker is running first:  `service docker status` (if it is not running the command to run it is: `service docker start`)
- run docker as root or use sudo